# Is there a way to get Bootstrap Cols to flow more naturally?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Currently I am using BS3 (can't go to 4 yet, cards look nice) and I can't figure out a way to get the columns to flow right.  I have everything in the same "row" but they do not wrap "naturally" - is there a way to do that?  Here is a sweet paint drawing of what I mean, thank you:
[image]

Comment: No, not natively. Try looking at http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: This question gets asked a lot here, and it's the same answer: Bootstrap doesn't do this by default. Look into http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: You can use two columns (`col-md-6`) in one row and in the first column include all divs which you want to the left and in the second all divs you want to the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with bootstrap only you can not do it, But you can do it by combining bootstrap's grid functionality and [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) library,you will have something like this

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="col-sm-4">...</div> // col instead of item
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

this is a [working demo](http://codepen.io/aitnasser/pen/PZZgad)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like @aitnasser said, the **[Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)** library is the best place to get started if you want a way to get Bootstrap to work the way you like.

Personally I enjoy the **[Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)** library the most right now just as an add on. If you need to rely more on JQuery however, you should really be focusing on JQuery's dedicated implementation of **[Masonry](http://desandro.github.io/masonry/)**.

I understand your question is a little broad so feel free to ask any questions that may come up, or make a question about it.